# Draw method of subclassed UIView (child of another subclassed UIView) not called

Tags: c#, ios, uiview, xamarin, xamarin.ios

I have a subclassed parent `UIView` object which should add another subclassed `UIView`. This is the `UIView` I want to add and where the `Draw` method is not called:

```
public class Circle : UIView
{
    private UIColor color;

    public Circle ()
    {
        this.color = UIColor.Black;

        this.BackgroundColor = UIColor.Clear;
    }

    public Circle (UIColor color)
    {
        this.color = color;

        this.BackgroundColor = UIColor.Clear;
    }

    public override void Draw (CGRect rect)
    {
        base.Draw (rect);

        // Get the context
        CGContext context = UIGraphics.GetCurrentContext ();

        context.AddEllipseInRect (rect);
        context.SetFillColor (color.CGColor);
        context.FillPath ();
    }
}
```

This is how I'm adding the *circle*:

```
Circle circle = new Circle (UIColor.Red);
circle.TranslatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false;
AddSubview (circle);

AddConstraint(NSLayoutConstraint.Create(circle, NSLayoutAttribute.Left, NSLayoutRelation.Equal, line, NSLayoutAttribute.Left, 1, 10));
AddConstraint(NSLayoutConstraint.Create(circle, NSLayoutAttribute.CenterY, NSLayoutRelation.Equal, line, NSLayoutAttribute.CenterY, 1, 0));
AddConstraint(NSLayoutConstraint.Create(circle, NSLayoutAttribute.Height, NSLayoutRelation.Equal, null, NSLayoutAttribute.NoAttribute, 1, 6));
AddConstraint(NSLayoutConstraint.Create(circle, NSLayoutAttribute.Width, NSLayoutRelation.Equal, null, NSLayoutAttribute.NoAttribute, 1, 6));
```

This code above is again in the `Draw` method of the parent. The objects in the parent are drawn fine except the circle and even if I use the below code as *circle* it is shown correctly. So the constraints are ok.

```
UIView circle = new UIView() { BackgroundColor = UIColor.Red };
```

What I'm doing wrong? Can't I override both `Draw` methods (in the subclassed parent and in the subclassed *circle*)?

PS: I have to mention that the circle should overlaps a line. But the `Draw` is never called so it seems that it doesn't get a frame.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Are you aware that you are instantiating an UIView and not a Circle in this code snipped ?

`UIView circle = new UIView() { BackgroundColor = UIColor.Red };`

Also you shouldn't add subview in the draw method, because it will be called multiple time, in fact you should only override the Draw method with you are doing a custom draw (it´s the case of the Circle view, but not the case of the parent view).

From apple documentations:

> View drawing occurs on an as-needed basis. When a view is first shown,
>   or when all or part of it becomes visible due to layout changes, the
>   system asks the view to draw its contents. For views that contain
>   custom content using UIKit or Core Graphics, the system calls the
>   view’s drawRect: method

So can you post the code snipe where you actually add the parent view? And the code of the parent view, you might have override a method and are not calling the base class method (like setNeedsDisplay or something similar) OR you are not adding the view.

Comment: I moved the code in the parent from `Draw` to the constructor and now the circle is shown! Thanks!